# Numpy get a 1d array from 2d array with an index array

Tags: python, numpy

My input array which I will call as `scores` will have a shape of (500, 10):

```
import numpy as np

scores = np.random.randint(10, size=(500, 10))
scores.shape # (500, 10)
```

Now I will have an indexing array with a creative name called `index` with shape (500, ):

```
index = np.random.randint(9, size=500)
index.shape # (500,)
```

The index array represents each index of a column in each row in `scores`. The objective would be to return an array of (500,) scores that correspond to each index in `index` per row.

An unvectorized equivalent of this procedure will look like below code:

```
score_vector = np.zeros(500)
for i, col in enumerate(index):
    score_vector[i] = scores[i, col]
```

My goal: an uber fast numpy vectorized version of above using api I don't really know.

Comment: Are you looking for `scores[np.arange(500), index]`?

Comment: yep! Thank you, leave it as an answer and I will vote it.

Comment: I believe this question has been answered before. I linked a related question.